# Latex compiles a source into the bibliography that is not in the Bibtex file

Tags: bibliographies

my Problem is, that I added a source to the Bibtexfile (created with citavi) which accidentally included a greek letter, the Φ. Then LaTeX gave me this error:
Undefined control sequence. ...goniometer for \textgreek{F}-positioning}
Despite the error it comiled the document and added the source to the bibliography but changed the greek phi to a "F".
Then I deleted the part where the Φ stands, reexported the BibTexfile from Citavi an recompiled. But the source in the bibliography didn`t change.
[image]

The part of the BibTexfile is the following:

```
@misc{attocubesystemsAG.c,
editor = {{attocube systems AG}},
 title = {ANGp101/UHV - goniometer for {\textquotedbl}phi{\textquotedbl} tilting},
 url = {https://www.attocube.com/en/products/nanopositioners/ambient-vacuum-nanopositioners/angp101uhv-goniometer-phi-tilting},
 urldate = {05.12.2021}
}
```

Here is what I've tried:
Compile without any bibliography and recompile with a new exportet BibTexfile where the Φ never was a part of.
But the output does not change form the picture above.
The problem that I have in addition is, that i can not cite any other sources that I have added since then in the BibTexfile.

Here is a list of all usepackages i have integraded for many reasons.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left= 2.5cm,right = 2cm, bottom = 4 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[color={1 0 .5}]{attachfile2}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,shadows,calc,matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}

\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\newcommand\tabrotate[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}

\newcommand{\frontmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
}

\newcommand{\mainmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}
```

Has someone a hint or even a solution of this problem?
I am happy about any help.
Thanks advance.

Comment: did you delete the bbl?

Comment: No to test it I created a new one with another name and put the old file in another folder. So for LaTeX it shouldnt make any difference if i delete that in addition.

Comment: you have posted a lot  of code but none of it is relevant to your question as you have shown nothing about the bibliography but you need to re-run bibtex (or perhaps biber, I can not tell from teh code shown) to re-generate the bibliography  whenever you edit the bib file or add or delete a `\cite`.

Comment: what do you mean with re-run bibtex?

Comment: Is there any specific code that would be helpfull?

Comment: Did you double check that your `.bib` file really has the contents it should have? (Ideally with a text editor.) Maybe you exported to a different file and left the original file unchanged. If you deleted the `.bbl` file (and the `.aux` for good measure) or otherwise made it unavailable and then rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (here "LaTeX" can be any of pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX depending on what you want to run) you should get a `.bbl` based on the current state of your `.bib` file.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but you may want to consider cleaning up your preamble a bit. Firstly, are you sure you need all the packages you load? Do you know what each package does and why you load it? Usually it is better to load as few packages as possible. Usually `hyperref` should be loaded last (there are a few documented exceptions, but loading it as second package is most likely not a good idea). `fancyhdr` and KOMA-Script classes (`scrreprt`) don't go together that well. With KOMA-Script classes it is recommended to look into `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: It works now!!! I didn't deleted the .aux befor, which seems to be necessary. Thanks alot for this specific hint and the other hints which were related to my preamble as well.